# HTML - XML - Jump to another tab/page element

Tags: javascript, html, xml, view, odoo

I need to jump to another element in my view. Simple jump in same element works with like this:

```
<page>
<a id="start"/>
...
...

<a href=#start>Up</a>
</page>
```

But if try it in this example, nothing happens:

```
<page>

  ...
  ...

  <a href=#next>Next Page</a>
</page>
<page>
  <a id="next"/>
</page>
```

The problem is, those pages are on same URL (or at at least URL does not change when you click on next page).

**About the problem.** There are many those so called pages which have lots of information and you need to scroll down. So when you reach bottom, I would like to just jump to next page with a button not needing to scroll back and press on that next page.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<page>
    <a id="next">Next</a>
</page>
```

to:

```
<div id="next">
    Full content of your next page
</div>
```

Anyway - I don't recommend this idea. You should just go to the new page - so put regular  link at the bottom of your page and load full page - instead of putting all the long pages on one page and just moving between divs.

Comment: Well that suggestion does not work. It hides whole page if I do that. If wrap with div inside next page, then it does not do anything too. But I think I'll stick with normal navigation to just jump up. Thanks anyway